# How to resolve this error while running the DocTR OCR model

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, ocr

I'm trying to run the pre-trained docTR ocr model in colab. But I'm facing this error fir some images:

> ValueError: Tensor's shape (1, 32, 26, 3) is not compatible with supplied shape [None, 32, 106, None].

Here is the code that I used:

```
!pip install python-doctr
!pip install "python-doctr[tf]"
!pip install "python-doctr[torch]"

from doctr.io import DocumentFile
from doctr.models import ocr_predictor
model = ocr_predictor(det_arch = 'db_resnet50', reco_arch = 'crnn_vgg16_bn', pretrained = True)


import cv2
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile
j=0
for filename in os.listdir(image_folder):
  input_image_path = os.path.join(image_folder, filename)
  # print(input_image_path)
  # print(image_folder)
  if filename.endswith('.jpg') or filename.endswith('.jpeg') or filename.endswith('.png'):
      image_bgr = DocumentFile.from_images(input_image_path)
      base_name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
      output_text_file = os.path.join(txt_folder, base_name + '.txt')
      print(j+1)
      j=j+1
      print(filename)
      text_result = model(image_bgr)
      
      output_text = text_result.export()
      with open(output_text_file, 'w') as file:
        for obj1 in output_text['pages'][0]["blocks"]:
          for obj2 in obj1["lines"]:
            for obj3 in obj2["words"]:
              file.write(obj3["value"]+' ')
        print(" __________ ")
```

The above code works well with a lot of images, while for some it produces errors.

Note: all the variables such as file names/ directory names are defined.